# Adding a Filter By 'Configuration' on Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Within TFS2013 we have a collection of Test Cases (On the web-side) and these are assigned out to different members of the team. Along the top of each Test Suite we can filter these tests by "Outcome", "Tester" & "View". I have seen instances where there are a lot more filters on this list and I'm curious how I can go about adding a Filter for "Configurations" to only show Tests that need ran on a specific environment instead of having to siphon through the tests.

Image:
http://prntscr.com/8sxpd8

Any ideas how to add to this list I appreciate; I've tried the usual searches and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to filter by "Configuration" on Team Web Access, but you can add tags for the Tests that need run on a specific environment.

Otherwise, you need to implement the function programmatically, you may check this blog: http://bzbetty.blogspot.com/2013/02/tfs-extensibility-filtering-lab.html